# Create a line passing through some points with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, line

I have a situation very similar to the one in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cc0ehz2/12/) with some points representing a team (in particular its final rank in a football season).

I would like to substitute the points with a line passing exactly in these points so that the final result shows the temporal evolution of each team in terms of final ranking position.

I know how to create a line by setting the `X1,X2,Y1,Y2` coordinates but I don't understand how to set this coordinates to the exact value (e.g. if the line is between season 2006-2007 and season 2007-2008 I will have to set `X1` and `Y1` with value from the first season as `d[0]` and `d[1]` but for `X2` and `Y2` I need values from the next element in the array.

I'm very new with D3.js so any advice and solution is very welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that fiddle, this is what I'd do:

First, I'd set a class to each team's circles (team1, team2 and so on...). So, I could later retrieve the circles' values for each team.

For retrieving the circles values, I'd use a for loop:

```
for(var j = 1; j < 4; j++){//this loops from "Team1" to "Team3"
var team = d3.selectAll("circle.Team" + j)[0];//selects the team by class
    for(var i = 0; i < team.length; i++){//this loops through the circles
        if(team[i+1]){//if the next circle exists
            svg.append("line")
                .attr("x1", d3.select(team[i]).attr("cx"))//this circle
                .attr("y1", d3.select(team[i]).attr("cy"))//this circle
                .attr("x2", d3.select(team[i+1]).attr("cx"))//the next circle
                .attr("y2", d3.select(team[i+1]).attr("cy"))//the next circle
                .attr("stroke", function(){
                    return _TEAM_COLORS_["Team" + j]
                });//sets the colours based on your object
        }
    }
};
```

Here is that fiddle, updated: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/6cc0ehz2/18/

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped a lot! I made an update to your Fiddle to create the line for each Team. https://jsfiddle.net/6cc0ehz2/20/     
Thanks again

Comment: I already edited the fiddle, there is a line for each team now, in the team's color. But I just saw your fiddle, and your solution is better: using `Object.keys` is preferable than using magic numbers in the outer loop!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already declared some data for your lines drawing the actual lines based on that data is as simple as this:

1. create the X and Y scales:

   ```
   var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([dataRange.x1, dataRange.x2]).range([plotRange.x1, plotRange.x2]);
   var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([dataRange.y1, dataRange.y2]).range([plotRange.y1, plotRange.y2]);
   ```
2. declare the line function:

   ```
   var valueLine = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function (dataItem, arrayIndex) {
       return xScale(dataItem);
   })
   .y(function (dataItem, arrayIndex) {
       return yScale(dataItem)
   });
   ```
3. and finally create the path:

   ```
   g.append("path")
       .style("stroke", someColour)
       .attr("d", valueLine(myData))
       .attr("class", "someClass");
   ```

Refer to more documentation here: https://www.dashingd3js.com/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand one thing. What is `myData` that I have to pass to the function? I tried in my example in the Fiddle but cannot make it work.

Comment: myData in this case is a json array of coordinates with your your series of lines

Comment: hi, sure, I've updated it with the simplified version. Lines are drawn in one colour but obviously it should be easy to modify

Comment: If you can share the link of the fiddle, cause I can't see it.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I was away for a few days. https://jsfiddle.net/nevseev/x607zszw/

Comment: No problem, at the end I found your fiddle but I still have a problem, maybe you can help me again. What if for each team I want to draw lines only for values inside a range, for example: only years in which the team arrived in the first 5 position. In our Fiddle I tried something like: `if(dataItem[1] > 1){ return null;} else{ return xScale(dataItem[0]); }`        In the `valueLine()` function, but with `null` it always get the top-left point, so each of these lines I don't want to draw are still visible and start from the top left corner.

Comment: so essentially you want to draw broken lines? how are they meant to connect? it would greatly help in understanding your idea if you could put together a visual sketch

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want broken lines because I'm using a dataset with information about each season but of course some teams are promoted and relegated so they are not always present (but they are in my data structure). So what I want to do is: for each season, select only the first 20 teams (that played this year), if they were present also in the precedent season --> create the line, otherwise don't. (I'll try to put together the visual sketch)

Comment: With the solution proposed by Gerardo Furtado I achieved my objective simply by connecting with a 'line' element only circles that are shown. But I think your solution is more elegant and flexible so I would like to implement it, but I can't fix this problem.

Comment: how about simply segmenting your data by whatever rules you want to apply and then create paths for each segment? i.e. have a segment per team per period. Thus you'll be able to achieve the breaks